# Symfony 4 redirect loop to login form multiple role

Tags: symfony, security, authentication, redirect-loop

I'm setting up Symfony 4 to create new website, but when I want to login with user, who have multiple role `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`, I'm redirected to login page. With just one role `ROLE_USER` I can login, How to solve this problem ?

Configuration is PHP 7.2, Symfony 4.2, Web Server Built-in Symfony "server:start".
I've tried to change security configuration but nothing change.

security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            # this firewall applies to all URLs
            pattern: ^/

            # but the firewall does not require login on every page
            # denying access is done in access_control or in your controllers
            anonymous: ~

            # This allows the user to login by submitting a username and password
            # Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
            form_login:
                # fos user bundle handles the form login
                #provider: fos_userbundle
                # The route name that the login form submits to
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                # The name of the route where the login form lives
                # When the user tries to access a protected page, they are redirected here
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                # Secure the login form against CSRF
                # Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/csrf_in_login_form.html
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager

            logout:
                # The route name the user can go to in order to logout
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                # The name of the route to redirect to after logging out
                target: homepage

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/categories, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/tags, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/typewords, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

routes.yaml

```
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: '@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/EasyAdminController.php'
    prefix: /admin
    type: annotation
```

I expect to login with another `ROLE` than `ROLE_USER`.

Comment: What errors occurs while you trying login with  ROLE_ADMIN user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By hierarchy, a user with `ROLE_ADMIN` automatically has the `ROLE_USER`. So just remove `ROLE_USER` from that user. Not sure how the roles are loaded from the user provider, check also how `ROLE_ADMIN` is written in the database or what you use to map the User entity. (Include the mapping file for the user entity for further insight)

Comment: After some test i have change User Entity and now i can logging. 
I use now : [link](https://github.com/sharfaz/Symfony3-Admin-Template/blob/master/src/SalexUserBundle/Entity/User.php)